# get a final Boolean value from ArrayList<Boolean>

Tags: arraylist, boolean

I want to get a final Boolean value using an operator ( && or || ) from an ArrayList of Boolean. I have Method a which returns Boolean and sometimes it also returns Null value. As Boolean accepts Null values also. So it is actually a combination of Null and Boolean values in the ArrayList.

Comment: I am sure this is not the way to get that though. Please read [how to ask guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).